# AWS: Lambda submits a Batch job via Python boto3 client but times out before receiving a response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I have a Lambda function that has a Python handler that submits a job to AWS Batch via `boto3` client:

```py
client = boto3.client('batch', 'us-east-1')

def handle_load(event, context):

    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    hasher.update(str(time.time()).encode())
    job_name = f"job-{hasher.hexdigest()[:10]}"
    job_queue = os.environ.get("job_queue")
    job_definition = os.environ.get("job_definition")

    logger.info(f"Submitting job named '{job_name}' to queue '{job_queue}' "
                f"with definition '{job_definition}'")

    response = client.submit_job(
        jobName=job_name,
        jobQueue=job_queue,
        jobDefinition=job_definition,
    )

    logger.info(f"Submission successful, job ID: {response['jobId']}")
```

I can see this Lambda function submit the Batch job in CloudWatch logs but it always times out before the response comes back. I never see these jobs show up in the queue, so I'm not sure where things go after they are submitted, it seems that the Lambda is always timing out before the response comes back, I have little else to go on.

I have successfully added a job to the queue via AWS CLI, using the same queue and definition ARNs that are used in the Lambda's Python code. This job can be seen in the queue under the runnable tab (presumably the job will be started at some point in the near future).

The job submission with AWS CLI comes back instantly, so there must be something amiss on the Lambda configuration preventing the job submission. Perhaps I'm not using the correct role for the Lambda that submits the job, or have some other permissions that are amiss causing the timeout? The Lambda has permission for the `batch:SubmitJob` action allowed on all resources.

Comment: Have you adjusted your lambda's timeout time? Default is 3 seconds.

Comment: Yes, the timeout is 300 seconds.

Comment: So the actual call `client.submit_job()` is timing out? Is your lambda in VPC?

Comment: The second log message is never seen and the CloudWatch log shows a timeout after 300 seconds, so I assume the response never comes back as a result of timing out? The Lambda is in a VPC. Do you ask because I may need to further configure the Batch service to be on the same VPC? If so then should this be set on the compute environment, job queue, and/or job definition?

Comment: Yes. Lambda in VPC requires special treatment. I added more info in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If an AWS Lambda function is *not* connected to a VPC, then by default it is connected to the Internet. This means it can call AWS API functions, which resides on the Internet.

If your Lambda function is **configured to use a VPC**, it will not have Internet access by default. This is good for connecting to other resources in a VPC, but if you wish to communicate with an AWS service, you'll either:

- A **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet, with the Lambda function connected to a private subnet that has a Route Table rule that points to the NAT Gateway, or
- A [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) that connects to the desired service. Unfortunately, AWS Batch does not have a VPC Endpoint.

So, if your Lambda function does not need to connect to other resources in the VPC, you can **disconnect it** and it should work. Otherwise, use a **NAT Gateway**.

Comment: This is enlightening. I really appreciate your help, John.

Comment: [AWS Batch adds support for AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/aws-batch-adds-privatelink/)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments. Lambda in a VPC does not have access to internet. You need to setup **internet gateway** in public subnet and **NAT gateway** in private subnet with your lambda to be able to access AWS Batch endpoints. Alternatively have to use **VPC interface endpoint** for AWS Batch. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connect your function to private subnets to access private resources. If your function needs internet access, use NAT. Connecting a function to a public subnet **does not give it internet access or a public IP address**.

Also you need to add permissions to your **lambda's execution role** to be able to create **network interface** in VPC:

- ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
- ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
- ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks like I have some further Terraforming to do, but at least now I have some good guidance to work with. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can configure Batch to be used with a VPC Endpoint, as there's no associated ServiceName currently supported? If you create a VPC endpoint in the console, batch is not a recognised service.